# Como fazer um relacionamento de models recursivo em NodeJS (Adonis)?

Tags: node.js, adonisjs

Olá, Estou com uma duvida que não encontrei em lugar nenhum ainda (ou não soube como procurar).
No Laravel/CakePHP eu consigo facilmente relacionar models e fazer queries com models de forma recursiva.

Como posso fazer com o Adonis Js que uma query no meu **Board** traga as **tarefas** e nas **Tarefas** traga o **Status**?

```
boards: {
   name: 'Meu board',
   tasks: {
      { 
         name: 'Tarefa 1',
         status: {
            name: 'Médio'
         }
      },
      { 
         name: 'Tarefa 2',
         status: {
            name: 'Alto'
         }
      },
   }
}
```

Segue os models:

Model board (tem varias tarefas)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Model tarefas só tem um board e um status

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o Model status tem varias tarefas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no controller do board faço a query com with.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi resolvido da seguinte forma...

Controller Board:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e no model Task:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]